# How to calculate daily average in django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my model :

```
class Record(models.Model):
        type = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=RECORD_CHOICES)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        record = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4,max_digits=8)
        date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

my serializer:

```
 class RecordSerializer_1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['type','record','date_time']
```

my view :

```
  records = Record.objects.filter(user=user,type="HeartRate")
        serializer = RecordSerializer_1(records, many=True)
```

I have more than one record at same day , I need to calculate average and return only one record per day

Comment: So you want to calculate an average over records on the same day, but what record will you return? The resulting average might be a decimal which is not a record.

Answer (score 0):

To get the average of a record given datetime:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

# Ex records:
records = [2, 3, 4, 7, 9]

day = datetime.datetime.now()
agg = Record.objects.filter(date_time=day).aggregate(record_average=Avg("record"))
# {'record_average': Decimal('5')}
```

You can have a look at the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/) for more about aggregation.

Comment: First :
I have list of day not only one day 
second: 
How to use it in serializer
Best Regards (:

Comment: I do not quite understand, you have a list of (different) days? I thought you wanted a daily average of the records of the day? Do you have a list of days and you want a daily average of each days? Regarding the second issue, you will have to sort out your requirement first. Do you need a to get an average out of the records, or do you need an explicit record?